# ASP.NET core published Project - JavaScript not functioning on all devices

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, server

I published my Website with Visual Studio 2017 **ASP.NET core 2.1** to my Server and I can open the Website hosted on the server with a different Computer.

Everything is fine, but when I open it from the Server itself some Elements won't work like showing the drop down menu when clicking on a button or showing the HTML Editor I build in.
It seems that **JavaScript** isn't working properly.
I checked the Browser version:

Windows Server 2016 PC: Internet Explorer 11.447..
Windows 7 Professional PC: Internet Explorer 11.0..

that shouldn't be the problem. 
I open up the DOM Explorer in my Browser and every JavaScript file I included is loaded.

What can be the Problem?
What else is responsible for correctly using Javascript than the Browser?
Is it really a Javascript problem?

Comment: Can you check the network tab of browser for any required javascript file not being loaded, when you open website on server itself?

Comment: There aren't any Javascript listed. Only CSS files and the HTML file. I also looked at the other PC and the JS files are shown in the Network tab.